# Unable to Understand how layout works in PyQt Designer

Tags: pyqt5

well... what the title thread says, i would like to create a simple interface that properly resize when the main window size is changed, so i tried setting a layout and putting my button inside the layout using QTDesigner, however when i resize the windows, the button does not resize while it does resize in other examples found on the internet using Layouts, so i don't understand what i'm doing wrong exactly

the code is as follow

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
       self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
       self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 541, 361))
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
       self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
       self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
       MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
       self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
       self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
       MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
       self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
       self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
       MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

       self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: alright, i now realize this is a more complicated question than i thought at first, basically i'm trying to use layout to create an interface like this, (the green bit are progress bars, the grey bits are button and the artwork at the center is a label) it was easy to do without layouts but now that i'm trying to use layouts i'm a bit confused how to go about it,
i just want this interface to resize and shrink if the windows size become smaller than the interface itself

[Interface Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Iyo.png)

Comment: You must set a layout for the central widget. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html#setting-a-top-level-layout

Comment: that works, the button is now resizing correctly, but it's now placed on the center of the window and i can't move it from where i want it, i want my button to be in a fixed place and simply resize when the window size changes